# Oracle TKPROF Insert data doesn't match text results

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, windows

I'm trying to make sense of the output from a SQL Trace from an Oracle 12.2 database on Windows. I've used TKPROF to interpret the the resulting trace files. This utility generates a text file output and a SQL file output. But the data don't match up between the two files.

The data was generated using syntax like `tkprof Trace.trc trace.trc.txt insert=trace.trc.sql`

For a specific query, the TKPROF output via text file is:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute     13      0.04       0.03          0          0          1           0
Fetch       13      0.00       0.07          6         26          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total       27      0.04       0.11          6         26          1           0
```

But TKPROF's SQL output generates data for that query that doesn't have the same numbers for the Elapsed column.

Here's the Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO tkprof_table (
    date_of_insert, cursor_num, depth, user_id,
    parse_cnt,   parse_cpu, parse_elap, parse_disk, parse_query, parse_current, parse_miss,
    exe_count,   exe_cpu,   exe_elap,   exe_disk,   exe_query,   exe_current,   exe_miss,  exe_rows,
    fetch_count, fetch_cpu, fetch_elap, fetch_disk, fetch_query, fetch_current, fetch_rows,
    ticks, sql_statement
    )
VALUES
(
  SYSDATE, 4, 0, 9, 
  1, 0, 86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  13,46875, 31424, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0,
  13, 0, 79075, 6, 26, 0, 0, 152918 
, 'SELECT [...]')
```

And then converting those SQL columns to match the text file's table layout that becomes:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed    disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0       86          0          0          0           0
Execute     13      46875   31424       0          0          1           0
Fetch       13      0       79075       6         26          0           0
```

Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/sqltrace.htm#PFGRF94992) says the TKPROF Elapsed values are

> "total elapsed time in seconds for all parse, execute, or fetch calls
>   for the statement."

And I believe that's accurate for the text file output. But the SQL data must be some other measure. I can't find any documentation that defines a unit of measure for the mismatched data.

There's a "ticks" column, that appears to correspond to CPU ticks. But I don't know if that's what the mismatched values are too. If so, how do I convert that data to seconds?

Or it looks like these values *may* be microseconds. Is that correct? Is there anywhere that definitively defines that unit of measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are just fine. They are just truncated in the tkprof output and displayed as seconds instead of microseconds.

Time for SQL executions is typically measured in microseconds.

See [V$SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/V-SQL.html) for example:

> ELAPSED_TIME
>
> NUMBER
>
> Elapsed time (in microseconds) used by this cursor for parsing,
>   executing, and fetching. If the cursor uses parallel execution, then
>   ELAPSED_TIME is the cumulative time for the query coordinator, plus
>   all parallel query slave processes.

Tkprof also displays time in microseconds at the row source operations section (and displays the unit as `us`).

I did not find any explicit reference for describing all the columns of TKPROF_TABLE, stating the time unit to be microsecond, but its quite logical.